# How to install arrow for R to access HDFS

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'd like to access parquet files on HDFS and would like to use [arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow) library. However, I need to know what other dependencies need to be installed on the client side? For instance, the [following page](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html) explained what dependencies are required to use arrow for python (pyarrow) but I can't find those dependencies for R.

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.14.1, the R arrow bindings don't yet have HDFS support. Your best bet at the moment is probably to sync the files to your local filesystem before working with them.

Comment: Sorry, I notice 0.14.1 version is very recent. Is there any where in the documentation where they explicitly mention that they no longer support HDFS? How about the old version? How can I use an older version arrow to connect to HDFS?

Comment: The arrow R package has never had HDFS support. The C++ library does support it, but R bindings have not been written yet.

Comment: are you aware of any other lib which support reading parquet files from HDFS?

Comment: Not in R, no. Hence why I suggested using another package or service to sync the Parquet files locally and then use `arrow` to read them.